# What should I override to use ArrayAdapter<T>.getPosition?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

This is using Xamarin.Android and with an [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter/) to bunch together instances of a quite simple POCO:

```
public class Subject
{
    public Guid SubjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Calling [`ArrayAdapter.GetPosition`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Widget.ArrayAdapter.GetPosition/p/Java.Lang.Object/) always results in a return code of `-1`. I then recalled, that the lookup might be implemented in some Java Code, so I attempted to implement `equals` on my `Subject` class, but surprisingly this doesn't change the result.

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return (obj != null && obj is Subject && (obj as Subject).SubjectId == SubjectId);
}
```

I was thinking about also implementing the `==` Operator, but [MSDN warns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> Overriding operator == in non-immutable types is not recommended.

My Type is clearly not immutable, so I decided to ignore the warning an implement `operator ==` anyway:

```
public static bool operator == (Subject lhs, Subject rhs)
{
    return ((object)lhs != null && (object)rhs != null && lhs.Equals(rhs));
}
```

But this does not persuade `ArrayAdapter.GetPosition` to actually find some candidate. Lurking around in the debugger tells me, that both methods are never called.

Frustrated, I wrote my own Method called `FindIndex`, which probably more or less exactly duplicates what `getPosition` could do:

```
public int FindIndex(Predicate<T> pred)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
    {
        if (pred(this[i]))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

For the moment, I call it like this: `subjectAdapter.FindIndex((candidate) => candidate.Equals(initialSubject));` and it works just fine. But this feels like re-inventing the wheel.

How should I proceed to behave like a "good citizen" that makes use of the APIs that are provided within the framework?

Comment: Why are you inheriting from ArrayAdapter? I would suggest you use BaseAdapter instead for C# managed types such as yours. This way you can also implement your own FindIndex or GetPosition method based on a managed C# List instead of a wrapped ArrayList.

Comment: Fair enough, but it requires me to do some more work: `ArrayAdapter` also provides `SetDropDownViewResource` and an implementation of `GetView` which I would need to double if deriving from `BaseAdapter`. Before doing that I prefer sticking with my current workaround, but I'm still curios to find out what I am doing wrong.